# What does o2m, m2o, m2m stands for?

Tags: acronym

While reading documentation or code comments, one may meet terms *o2m*, *m2o*, *m2m*. What do they stand for?

Also what do they mean?

Answer (score 3):

They are abbreviations of [cardinalities used in data modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) for:

- one to many
- many to one
- many to many

So obviously one may also encounter o2o for *one to one* relations.

Comment: Sorry but as obvious as it may seems to you, I didn't know before I searched for the answer, and didn't found it on stackoverflow. I just hope that it may help the next person who will be in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have O2O:

- One-to-One (O2O)
- One-to-Many (O2M)
- Many-to-One (M2O)
- Many-to-Many (M2M)

[List of Technology Acronyms](http://www.whiterootmedia.com/database/dusty_arlia/list_of_technology_acronyms.html)